# The \not\mid symbol is not working well

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I have seen a lot of issues regarding LaTeX being posted here and very recently i have noted one LaTeX. The **\not\mid** Symbol is not showing properly. It's showing like this: $p \not\mid q$. You may check this post: [Importance of Cayley's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10029/importance-of-cayleys-theorem/10035#10035)

Comment: It rendered for me after I refreshed, but you shouldn't be using \not\mid: \nmid looks much nicer.

Comment: @Qiaochu: It was giving me error! Let me check $p \nmid q$

Comment: @Qiaochu: yes its giving me error! $p \nmid q$

Comment: You can use a\not|b $\to a \not| b$ but it renders poorly as you can see. Both of these problems should be fixed since "not divides" is a common thing to say in number theory.

Comment: @Bill: \nmid is available in a standard package, I think amsmath or amssymb.  I don't know why MathJax doesn't support it.  In any case, it's not a math.SE issue, it's either an SE issue or a MathJax issue.

Comment: [To get $\nmid$ to work in MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/tex.html#supported-latex-commands), one needs to [configure MathJax to load the `AMSsymbols` extension](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/tex.html#amsmath-and-amssymbol). This is a job for the math.SE admins.

Comment: It's a LaTeX issue; if you type `\not\mid` or `\not|` in LaTex/TeX, it renders as poorly as it is rendered by MathJax; that is, after all, why `\nmid` was created in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rahul stated in the comment, we need to enable AMSsymbol to support `\nmid`. However, what AMSsymbol does is simply assign `\nmid` to `∤` (U+2224), so you could use the latter as a workaround now.

> ```
> p ∤ q
> ```
>
> $$ p ∤ q $$

See [Tex \implies symbol does not work](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/692/tex-implies-symbol-does-not-work) for detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is completed as you can see here

[Please enable AMSsymbols extension for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/please-enable-amssymbols-extension-for-mathjax)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!