# TeX beth symbol missing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tex \implies symbol does not work](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/692/tex-implies-symbol-does-not-work)

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10096/examples-of-sets-whose-cardinalities-are-aleph-n-or-any-large-cardinal-no/10123#10123) I cannot get the TeX symbol $\beth$ to work. I checked and the symbol does work on MathOverflow, so it may just be a configuration issue.

I have now made a request about the AMSsymbols extension at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/please-enable-amssymbols-extension-for-mathjax

Comment: I want to point out this is *not* a duplicate, because that other question linked above was about a different symbol. I searched for any question about the beth symbol before posting this question and there was none. The fact that both questions are apparently caused by the same underlying problem does not make them "exact duplicates".

Comment: I agree.  Just because the same answer functions for two questions does not make them the same.  In this particular case the closure of the question makes it look like the moderators/administrators are being actively unhelpful to the needs of the users.  If you find it tedious to get multiple questions prompted by the fact that the AMSsymbols package isn't properly working on this site, then the useful response would be....(it's obvious, isn't it?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MathJax supports the beth symbol upon enabling the `AMSsymbols` extension](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). This is something the StackExchange admins would have to fix. People have been running into this problem before [[1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/the-not-mid-symbol-is-not-working-well), [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/971/revisions)].

May I recommend that you change your question into a general request for enabling `AMSsymbols` in MathJax?